# Access TIMA keystore

Tags: android, samsung-knox

I'm trying to invoke the samsung knox SDK to access the TIMA keystore.

However, the device throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10207 does not have com.samsung.android.knox.permission.KNOX_TIMA_KEYSTORE.
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1966)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1934)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1884)
    at com.samsung.android.knox.keystore.ITimaKeystore$Stub$Proxy.enableTimaKeystore(ITimaKeystore.java:253)
    at com.samsung.android.knox.keystore.TimaKeystore.enableTimaKeystore(TimaKeystore.java:123)
    at com.samsung.knox.example.knoxsdk.MainActivity.enableKeystore(MainActivity.java:163)
    at com.samsung.knox.example.knoxsdk.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:157)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7957)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7779)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4615)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4664) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1960) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7094) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

What do I need to do to make it work?
I am working on a Samsung SM-A705FN and it does have knox on it

Sample code

```
private void enableTimaKeystore() {
    activateLicense();
    int checkKeystore = getApplicationContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(KNOX_KEYSTORE_PERMISSION);
    int checkKeystorePerApp = getApplicationContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(KNOX_KEYSTORE_PERMISSION_PER_APP);

    if (checkKeystore == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), KNOX_KEYSTORE_PERMISSION + " is granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        enableKeystore();

    } else if (checkKeystorePerApp == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), KNOX_KEYSTORE_PERMISSION_PER_APP + " is granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), KNOX_KEYSTORE_PERMISSION + " and " + KNOX_KEYSTORE_PERMISSION_PER_APP + " are not granted. You can't use TimaKeystorePerApp ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        requestPermissions(new String[]{KNOX_KEYSTORE_PERMISSION}, 100);

    }

}

 private void activateLicense() {

    // Instantiate the EnterpriseLicenseManager class to use the activateLicense method
    KnoxEnterpriseLicenseManager klmManager = KnoxEnterpriseLicenseManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());

    try {
        // KPE License Activation TODO Add license key to Constants.java
        klmManager.activateLicense(Constants.KPE_LICENSE_KEY);
        mUtils.log(getResources().getString(R.string.activate_license_progress));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        mUtils.processException(e, TAG);
    }
}


    private void enableKeystore() {
    /* get CCM Policy */
    TimaKeystore mTimaKeyStorePolicyHandler = EnterpriseKnoxManager.getInstance(this).getTimaKeystorePolicy();
    mTimaKeyStorePolicyHandler.enableTimaKeystore(true);

    /* To enable TimaKeystore for all the apps on the device (both inside and outside container). */

    boolean isEnabled = mTimaKeyStorePolicyHandler.isTimaKeystoreEnabled();

    mUtils.log("is keystore enabled: " + isEnabled);
}

   @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    enableKeystore();
}
```

And the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Permissions TODO List permissions used by application -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.knox.permission.KNOX_HW_CONTROL" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.knox.permission.KNOX_TIMA_KEYSTORE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.knox.permission.KNOX_KEYSTORE_PER_APP" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name="com.samsung.knox.example.knoxsdk.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- SampleAdminReceiver TODO Provide receiver for device admin receiver class -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.samsung.knox.example.knoxsdk.SampleAdminReceiver"
        android:description="@string/enterprise_device_admin_description"
        android:label="@string/enterprise_device_admin"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin_receiver" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Activate License TODO Provide receiver for Knox license activation results -->
    <receiver android:name="com.samsung.knox.example.knoxsdk.SampleLicenseReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.samsung.android.knox.intent.action.KNOX_LICENSE_STATUS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Comment: Strange looks like Samsung SDK is using own keystore. Take look [here](https://seap.samsung.com/html-docs/android/Content/knox-tima-keystore-access.htm#)

Comment: I did that, i ran their SDK, and it's not working, i downloaded the sample app and tried to do what i needed. Look at sample code i used

Comment: Wait let me check I am using the same SDK in one of my app but I don't remember

Answer (score -1):

Who would have thought that a public forum was the best place for questions like this. Maybe should listen to some John Lennon. Or a specific beatle

Comment: :/   comment must be at least 15 characters in length